# Indexed Query Optimisation = SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

This is a part of my past exam questions -

Optimise the following and assume there is an index on Members.lname :

```
SELECT fname, lname 
FROM Members 
WHERE lname <> 'Rogers' 
  AND memberType='Student';
```

I have therefore tried:

```
SELECT fname, lname 
FROM Members 
WHERE lname > 'Rogers' OR lname < 'Rogers'AND memberType='Student';
```

I tried this as splitting the <> forces the use of the index - my answer is however wrong. I was wondering if anyone could help and point me in the right direction?

Comment: lname <> 'Rogers' ?

Comment: If you use `or` and `and` you have to add brackets arround `or` like `(lname > 'Rogers' OR lname < 'Rogers' ) AND memberType='Student'`

Comment: How much data does your table have? Have you done analyze table after data insertion?

Comment: *<>* means _not equal to_, and splitting it won't get you any performance increase since MySQL would use the index in either case. It also reduces the number of comparisons from 3 to 2. I presume there is a typo in your first statement right before the *<>*.

Comment: @jarlh it is an exam question so it is theoretical

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name we are using pgAdmin for this course

Comment: I would be surprised if changing the condition from `<>` to `.. > .. and .. < ..` would change anything. The optimizer chooses an  index based on the estimation on how many rows this would remove from the overall result. If the condition only removes very few rows, it's  unlikely an index will be used - regardless of the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion the original query itself cannot be optimized.

That there is an index on `lname` should have no impact on the query. All members will have a name and few members will be Rogers. So the DBMS should not use the index, but simply read the full table.

"Optimise the following", however, may allow to optimize the query indirectly by creating another index. This index should at least contain and start with `memberType`:

```
create index idx1 on members (membertype);
```

Whether this index will be used for the query will probably depend on what's in the table. If 99% of the members are students, the DBMS should read the full table instead. If it's only few students (say 3%) then using the index makes sense, and the DBMS would use the index to find the students in the table and then check `lname` in the record.

Having said this, we might want this instead:

```
create index idx2 on members (membertype, lname);
```

so the DBMS reads the index, finds the students, sees immediately if the name is Rogers, and only accesses the table for the desired records.

An even better index still would be a covering index containing all columns in question, so the table doesn't have to be read anymore, as all the information is in the index:

```
create index idx3 on members (membertype, lname, fname);
```

As mentioned, the DBMS may *still* read the full table instead when it assumes that most records will match anyway. Indexes are only an offer to the DBMS which it may use or not.